# Condicionante para mostrar un boton

Tags: html, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas tardes, espero pueda conseguir respuestas aqui.
Estoy trabajando en ASP.net Razor 5 y Entity Framework
Tengo un listado en el que tengo un boton llamado HABILITAR.
Necesito que ese boton habilitar unicamente se muestre si cierto usuario esta logeado.
Puedo hacerlo directo en el html?
Un poco del codigo:

```
<div class="container panel-table">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("usuariosGrid").Columns(
         columns =>
         {
         columns.Add(c => c.Nombre).Titled("Nombre");
         columns.Add(c => c.UserName).Titled("Usuario");
         columns.Add(c => c.Iniciales).Titled("Iniciciales");
         columns.Add(c => c.Cargo).Titled("Cargo");
         columns.Add(c => c.Email).Titled("Email");
         columns.Add(c => c.FechaText).Titled("Fecha de Nacimiento");
         columns.Add(c => c.HabilitadoText).Titled("Habilitado");
         columns.Add(c => c.RoleName).Titled("Rol");
         columns.Add(c => c.Sucursal).Titled("Sucursal");
         columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(c => @<a href="@Url.Action("UserEdit", "account", new { Id = @c.Id })" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</a>);

         columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(c => @<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs habilitar" id="Habilitar" data-id="@c.Id">Habilitar</a>);

         columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(0).RenderValueAs(c =>
        @<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnEliminar" data-id="@c.Id">Eliminar</a>);

         }
    ).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).WithMultipleFilters().Selectable(true).SetLanguage("es").Filterable(true)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí muestras el botón dependiendo del nombre del usuario logueado:

```
@if (User.Identity.GetUserName() == "Maximiliano")
    {
        <button class="btn btn-success">Habilitar</button>
    }
```

y Aquí dependiendo del Roll del usuario.

```
  @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <button class="btn btn-success">Habilitar</button>
    }
```

espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Lo habia logrado gracias!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Para que funcione perfectamente enseguida de .Add() tenemos que renderizar el valor con RenderValueAs() y dentro del mismo abrir un @div donde podremos utilizar el @if de lo contrario no funcionara.
SOLUCION:

```
columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(c => @<div>
        @if (c.HabilitadoText == "Habilitado")
        {
            <i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>
        }
        else
        {
            <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i>
        }
    </div>).Titled("Estado");
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno explicar brevemente como el codigo resuelve el problema.